Capitalization of process names, specific terms etc (when is something a proper name)
EDIT:
Based on the comments to this post, I would like to refer to a few similar and partially related questions:

Should we capitalize Prisoner's Dilemma and when?
Proper Noun Capitalization for Type of Thing
Is it proper to capitalize the scientific method?
Capitalisation for emphasis?
Should the names of methods, processes or roles be capitalized?

However, in my personal opinion, they do not invalidate this question, as they all refer to very specific examples and never specify in general terms how to know if something is a proper name. The only minor exception is the last one, where the first answer speaks just about this, that "If, in using these terms, you make them into proper nouns (that is, they become the "official" name of something) then you can use capitals". It does not clarify how I would know/decide whether I have made a term into a proper noun (or a proper name, as in my question), so it does not answer this part of my question. Still, the answer do say that in the end it is anyway optional ("you can use capitals"), so in some way it does give a sort of answer to my question - it is a style choice whether to capitalise even if it is a proper name.
ORIGINAL:
I am part of a team that are writing a formal document that specifies a system. In this document, we have defined several functions, processes, objects, states, properties, etc, and now I am wondering how and when to captialize the words, or rather when these things become proper names.
Disclaimer: The following examples are fictional.
Example 1 - Our system has a function called "Time and energy monitoring" to monitor the time it takes and the energy consumed when executing other functions, actions, or processes. This function is also abbreviated and referred to as TEM throughout our documents (although the full name is also used from time to time). Is such a function name
a proper name?
Example 2 - Our system goes through different modes, e.g. "Initializing mode", "Sleeping mode", "Powering Down mode", etc. They all have their corresponding abreviation, e.g. "IN mode" for "Initialization mode". Are these mode names proper names, and if so, is the word "mode" to be considered as not part of the proper name?
Example 3 - Our system uses variables and properties with unique abbreviations, e.g. the variable "Error reaction type" (ERT), which value is received from an external source when executing a function, or the property "Execution Number" (ENO), which is a unique number that the system receives at the initialization and then uses to identify itself over the interface with other systems. Are such property names and variable names proper names?
Example 4 - If a function is defined with an abbreviation in its name, e.g. "ENO Update", is it a proper name?

I'm sure this has come up here before but I can't find the relevant question (however see this, this, this). Basically, in a corporate document you can choose to capitalize things that are important, and the main rule is to be as consistent as possible. Do you not have other documents you can compare?

You can use any abbreviated forms or initials you choose. There is no rule for this. However, take care and not use too many or the reader will have to go to your list of these things and look them up. These are not strictly speaking proper names, they are just nouns you have made up. But what difference would that make anyway?

If you have your own specific names for events and processes for which you often use an abbreviation, the document would be clearer if you capitalise TEM as "Time and Energy Monitoring" when you use it in full. It's then plain that isn't a casual phrase but a specific term. People generally only read the manual when they need to know something. So the clearer, the better. Perhaps even bolden these terms in the manual, when they have a specific meaning. If it's an electronic manual you can also easily cross-reference.

Well, a Windows professional manual has a lot of uppercase, a jarring amount, because they own that (and don't you forget it!), but you don't have to capitalize the words of an initialism, of course.

@StuartF, I agree that all of the three links you provided are related, however I could not find enough information in them to resolve my issue. Unfortunately, out of all the hundreds of documents that have been produced, there is no convention throughout the documents, and every time I try to enforce a convention, the response is that it is not worthwile. If I had support of proper grammar conventions, then it would be easier.

@Lambie, I was hoping to find a rule to be able to enforce a convention throughout all the hundreds of documents that we produce and which are currenlty not aligned, neither internally or between each other.

@WeatherVane, I agree that "Time and Energy Monitoring" looks more clearer. However, when I try to ask for alignment, the usual response from the formal editors of my particular document is rather to remove capitalisation. Although, this tendency is not aligned between all editors of all documents, and most documents are formatted on personal preference of the current editor (I have been guilty of this myself on the documents where I was the formal editor)

@EdwinAshworth, I agree that this other question is related to the topic, however I could not find sufficient answer to my question in the answers to that question. Perhaps the main reason to this is that it does not specify exactly whether it applies also to names of functions, processes, objects, states, properties, etc for a system. That is what I have been struggling to find.

@HippoSawrUs, I am not entirely sure what you mean with "Windows professional manual", is it a system manual for any of the Microsoft Windows Pro systems (like Windows 11 Pro), or is it a general professional manual for some Windows that may or may not be related to Microsoft? I also do not seek to capitalise all initialisms, I only include the initialism as I thought it might support that the name itself is a proper name. It is the name that is in question.

The decision is largely just a choice on the part of the author. Capitalising does give prominence to a noun / name, but is not mandatory. It may come across as rather grandiose where there is any doubt about whether a name should be capitalised. In essence, you can opt to treat these (being a grey area) as proper nouns.

@EdwinAshworth, would you go so far as to say that this is the general approach for these types of situations, that the document author/team of authors/organization should decide internally on the style guide for when to capitalise these types of specific terms and just try to be consistent internally? I can live with that approach, although I would have been more happy if there wold have existed a convention (in my opinion to treat these terms as proper names).

It was a professional reference book I was skimming for examples. I would expect a function name to be ALLCAPS and an App Name to have title capitalization: 'You have to download Security Check before you can perform a security check.' It makes it harder to see the difference when mega companies buy up all the common nouns… Best of luck.

Yes. There's a near-exact duplicate at Should the names of methods, processes or roles be capitalized? I've just discovered. The answer there is that this is a style choice. Perhaps you can examine similar cases / style guides and go with either which is the prevailing choice (if either) or which you prefer ... but as you say, be consistent. Rowling authored new proper nouns/names with "You-Know-Who" and the misnomer "He-Who-Must-Not-Be-Named" ... her choice. Hyphens and all.

@HippoSawrUs, This is my idea as well, to distinguish between a general action and a function/process with the same name as the action (as in your example) is to treat the function/process name as a proper name and capitalise.

@EdwinAshworth, I agree that this other question is also related (although I would not consider it close to a duplicate), however the answer in my opinion is not at all clear. Indeed, the answer indicate that it is a style choice, however the answer also states that if the person asking is making the names "official", then they should become proper names, without clarifying how to know whether a name is "official". I am also not agreeing that it is a style choice whether to capitalise proper names. That is in my understanding instead the convention.

'however the answer also states that if the person asking is making the names "official", then they should become proper names' means that style choices made by articulate authors often become the default (though rarely the mandatory) variants. So look for well-written articles etc with similar noun phrases, and follow their example. If this is too difficult, choose your preferred style ... you may become the pioneering articulate author.

@EdwinAshworth, oh, I would be happy if I could make that decision, but unfortunately I am not the responsible editor for any documents at the moment and even at the time when I was, I was only responsible for a very few documents and they were not sufficient to define the style guide for all others. This is why I am searching for support in the grammar community for my preferred style ;)

Grammar and style are largely non-comparable. And nowadays, most grammars are descriptivist rather than prescriptivist. There is no grammar czar in English (and the French often ignore theirs): usage drives acceptability.

I made up my example, but it was loosely based on an excerpt in the professional reference book. Their paragraph contained System Policy Editor (a tool), system policy (what you create with the tool), and 'with system policy (you can control…)' to mean…with the means to place restrictions, I suppose… Nobody likes all this mess in the same paragraph. No worries; they'll just ask the go-to guy/gal. It's more of a battle for clarity, but good luck.

Basically, in a corporate document you can choose to capitalize things that are important, and the main rule is to be as consistent as possible. Stuart F
You will almost certainly find no style guide addressing such a specific question, but all reasonable answers/comments at all the related questions mentioned do not conflict with Stuart's advice.
There is no punctuation czar to pontificate on such matters; the choice is that of the editors. Emphasis and clunkiness are opposing factors to weigh.
The only other approach is to search for closely related examples on the internet; almost certainly there will be divided usage, with even some inconsistencies within articles.
'Proper noun' is not a well-defined term; it has been argued that 'He Who Must Not Be Named' should be considered as a novel one post-Rowling (and "to He Who Must Not Be Named" is found on the internet and treats "He Who Must Not Be Named" as a single lexeme, avoiding "to Him Who Must Not Be Named"). Most commonly used proper nouns are obviously so, with logical reasons for so classifying them, but capitalisation to highlight is mostly a style choice.

Yes, and Edwin didn't bother - why would he - to mention that everything about this is greatly confused by the fact that headlines and captions, sub-titles and most other forms of 'non-standard' text are exempt from 'standard' rules.
